# Uncaught Error: createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element when refresh page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

i'm currently working on my portfollio using react js but i'm stuck with this error.

my portfollio is very simple, there is home section which is the component showed when you go on the website with the route "/", a project section and a contact section.

this error is only detected when i refresh page on "secondary pages", section and contact what redirect me to an 404 error on my website.

if somebody can help me i will be grateful :)

here is my app code with the routing, browserRouter is in index.js with app component in :

```
//import

import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Nav from "./components/Nav";
import GlobalStyle from "./components/GlobalStyle";
import ContactUs from "./pages/ContactUs";
import Projects from "./pages/projects";
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";


// import Routing
import { Route, Routes, useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
//animation
import {AnimatePresence} from "framer-motion";



//data

function App() {


  const location = useLocation();


  return (
    <div className="App">
          <GlobalStyle />
          <Nav />
          <AnimatePresence  exitBeforeEnter>
              <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
                  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                  <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactUs />} />
                  <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects/>} />
              </Routes>
          </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hello Mathias, where did you put your BrowserRouter component?

Comment: What are "secondary pages"? Do you mean any of the sub-routes? Are you running this code locally, or does it work locally and only become an issue once deployed somewhere?

Comment: @Drago96 Hi, the browserRouter component is in index.js  and contain the app component between his scriptag

Comment: hi @DrewReese, "secondary pages" means the other page than the main on which we arrive on my website. my roots for main page is "/" and for the other "/projects", "/contact". the problem appears locally : only on mobile version and when deployed on the both .

Comment: How are you running the app locally? What is serving it up locally? Where are you deploying the app to that also isn't working? This appears to be more an issue with how you are serving the app and nothing with the app itself.

Comment: yes you totaly right, i was looking for solution on netlify ( i'm using it to publish my app) forums and i see some body with a similar problem but i don't understand the solution, but they're talking about a netlify.toml file but i never heard about in every tutorial to publish react app i've seen. did you know something about that ?

Comment: ok i finally got the problem, it was about this netlify.toml file, i created one with "redirects" parameter in and it solved my problem, every thing work well, thank you for helping :)